# Type conversion using templates has odd behaviour

Tags: c++, string, templates, boolean

I have a function that aims to convert a string from a config file in to various different types. A special case has needed to be inserted to handle bool's as "false" equates to true when using a string stream.

Separate functions are not really an option as it would involve type checking for every type we are using.

The function worked correctly when part of a class previously, however to make it more usable it was moved in to its own start function. The function throws 2 errors on the return true's. The return false's are as expected.

Below is the code example and the errors thrown by visual studio.

```
template <typename T>
static T StringCast(string inValue)
{
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(bool))
    {
        if(inValue == "true")
            return true;
        if(inValue == "false")
            return false;
        if(inValue == "1")
            return true;
        if(inValue == "0")
            return false;
        return false;
    }

    std::istringstream stream(inValue);
    T t;
    stream >> t;
    return t;
}
```

Error   1   error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'

Error   2   error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'

Comment: http://ideone.com/1ZqKf compiles fine.

Comment: Calling it bool b = StringCast<bool>("true"); works fine under VS2010

Comment: @luskan don't mislead OP: http://ideone.com/0AKMJ

Comment: It's used from within another template function.
 template <typename T>
 T INIParser::GetValue(string key)
 {
  return StringCast<T>(this->iniData[key]);
 }

Comment: @LuchianGrigore don't mislead OP http://ideone.com/0AKMJ

Comment: @PiotrNycz **he's missleading us**!!!!!!!!!!! here's one more - http://ideone.com/Icjpi doesn't mean anything though.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't get your point. My point is that `T StringCast(string inValue)` won't compile for `T` not constructible from  `bool`: `true`/`false`, will it?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I don't see anything like that in the question. My point is that the question should provide more context.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore and should provide the answer too and your role is just copy the answer (JK). See error: `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'`  This was what I needed to provide proper answer.... Frankly I don't even need this errors - answer is obvious for me - but to show you the context which you overlooked.

Comment: @PiotrNycz of course :) My point wasn't to you, but to the op. I think people need to learn how to write good questions. Sure, some stuff you might deduce, but it doesn't hurt when everything is in the question to start off with.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore My personal opinion is that to write good question is harder than write good answer. And simple questions like this are written by people who start to play with templates - so we cannot expect them to be very good. If they could write good questions explaining their problems is proper way probably they would get the answer during writing questions... Just my personal opinion is that experienced users shall try to understand even not perfect questions .

Comment: @PiotrNycz I agree with that. That's why they need a bulge in that direction. :) I'm saying the question can be better because it doesn't give minimal code that reproduces the problem - which isn't that hard.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you are right - code causing presented errors is missing. The answer was so obvious that I did not notice that. Missing part, "auto-guessed" by me is `StringCast<std::string>(string inValue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have specialization for bool - then just define specialization for bool. Your way is not possible. Use the proper way below:

```
template <typename T>
T StringCast(string inValue)
{
    std::istringstream stream(inValue);
    T t;
    stream >> t;
    return t;
}

template <>
bool StringCast<bool>(string inValue)
{
        if(inValue == "true")
            return true;
        if(inValue == "false")
            return false;
        if(inValue == "1")
            return true;
        if(inValue == "0")
            return false;
        return false;
}

int main() {
   int a = StringCast<int>("112");
   bool b = StringCast<bool>("true"); 
}
```

Comment: We have success needed to make a few changes to get rid of linker redefnition errors, but thanks very much.